# XSLT conditional namespace and element

Tags: xml, xslt

I've working a XSLT and XML generation based on some rules. Now, I want to make a slight modification to XSLT file, the idea is as follows:

XSLT

- `bill:Receipt` root node **must** contain the attribute `xmlns:payment="http://www.website.io/Payments2"` only if `payments/payment` exist.
- At the same time, `<bill:Addendum>` **must** contain `<payment:Payments Version="2.0">` element only if if `payments/payment` exist.

As in the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <bill:Receipt xmlns:bill="http://www.website.io/bll/4"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.io/bll/4 http://www.website.io/site/bll/4/bllv40.xsd"
                        ReceiptType="{@ReceiptType}">
            <xsl:if test="payments/payment">
                <xsl:attribute name="xmlns:payment">
                    <xsl:value-of select="http://www.website.io/Payments2"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <bill:Addendum>
                <xsl:if test="payments/payment">
                    <payment:Payments Version="2.0">
                        <payment:Totals>
                            <xsl:attribute name="PaymentsTotal">
                                <xsl:value-of select="payments/totals/@PaymentsTotal"></xsl:value-of>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </payment:Totals>
                    </payment:Payments>
                </xsl:if>
            </bill:Addendum>
        </bill:Receipt>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Problem with this configuration is that I'm getting the error: `The prefix "payment" for element "payment:Payments" is not bound.` because the namespace is conditional.

I know that I can do something like this `<payment:Payments Version="2.0" xmlns:payment="http://www.website.io/Payments2">` (add the namespace to child element) but that implies my namespace won't be part of my root element `bill:Receipt` which is one of my requirements.

Is there another way to do it? Thanks!

-- EDIT

Thanks for the clarifications. Here are two different inputs and outputs expected, based on the XSLT.

Is there some example to take a look? Thanks. I'm still getting use to XSLT thing.

**Input 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bill ReceiptType="I">
    <payments/>
</bill>
```

**Output 1**: No `payment` namespace and no `payment` element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bill:Receipt xmlns:bill="http://www.website.io/bll/4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.io/bll/4 http://www.website.io/site/bll/4/bllv40.xsd" ReceiptType="I">
    <bill:Addendum></bill:Addendum>
</bill:Receipt>
```

**Input 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bill ReceiptType="I">
    <payments>
        <payment>...</payment>
        <totals PaymentsTotal="150.0"></totals>
    </payments>
</bill>
```

**Output 2**: `payment` namespace and `payment` element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bill:Receipt xmlns:bill="http://www.website.io/bll/4" xmlns:payment="http://www.website.io/Payments2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.io/bll/4 http://www.website.io/site/bll/4/bllv40.xsd" ReceiptType="I">
    <bill:Addendum>
        <payment:Payments Version="2.0">
            <payment:Totals PaymentsTotal="150.0" />
        </payment:Payments>
    </bill:Addendum>
</bill:Receipt>
```

Comment: `xmlns:payment="http://www.website.io/Payments2"` is a namespace declaration, not an attribute. It's not clear what you actually want to accomplish here. Perhaps post an example of the 2 possible inputs and the expected result of each.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for pointing that out. I've added some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:bill="http://www.website.io/bll/4" 
xmlns:payment="http://www.website.io/Payments2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/bill">
    <bill:Receipt 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.io/bll/4 http://www.website.io/site/bll/4/bllv40.xsd" 
    ReceiptType="{@ReceiptType}">
        <bill:Addendum>
            <xsl:if test="payments/payment">
                <payment:Payments Version="2.0">
                    <payment:Totals PaymentsTotal="{payments/totals/@PaymentsTotal}"/>
                </payment:Payments>
            </xsl:if>
        </bill:Addendum>
    </bill:Receipt>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would produce a redundant namespace declaration in the case of input 1 - but that should cause no problems if the target application employs a conformant parser.

Since you say that in the case of input 2 you must have the namespace declaration on the root element, we must assume that the target application's parser does NOT conform to standard. To accommodate such limitation, you need to convolute your code with some inelegant workaround - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:bill="http://www.website.io/bll/4" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/bill">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="payments/payment">
            <bill:Receipt 
            xmlns:payment="http://www.website.io/Payments2"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.io/bll/4 http://www.website.io/site/bll/4/bllv40.xsd" 
            ReceiptType="{@ReceiptType}">
                <bill:Addendum>
                    <payment:Payments Version="2.0">
                        <payment:Totals PaymentsTotal="{payments/totals/@PaymentsTotal}"/>
                    </payment:Payments>
                </bill:Addendum>
            </bill:Receipt>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <bill:Receipt 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.io/bll/4 http://www.website.io/site/bll/4/bllv40.xsd" 
            ReceiptType="{@ReceiptType}">
                <bill:Addendum/>
            </bill:Receipt>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note that the XSLT processor may decide to put the namespace declaration/s anywhere that is in-scope for the relevant nodes. I have tested the above with several processors, but your processor may behave differently. Ultimately, the best solution would be to have a conformant parser at the target application and avoid this or some other elaborate workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Definitely it's really convoluted in XSLT 1.0, so using two transformers would be cleaner. And the main issue is that the target application doesn't use a conformant parser. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not convinced it can be much less convoluted in XSLT 2.0, if at all. The question is what are the true limitations here. If the target application is willing to accept the results produced by the 1st stylesheet above, in both scenarios, then you have a simple solution.

Comment: Exactly that's the issue, the target application doesn't accept the redundant namespace. Anyway, in the 1st stylesheet the namespace is always there, even for input 1 and that's failing in the parser. So, I'll use two transforments in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT, namespaces are not attributes. Generally, you don't need to create namespace declarations: if you create your elements (and attributes) in the right namespace, the namespace declarations will be produced automatically.

If you really need to produce a namespace declaration on the root element, when it's not actually used in the name of the element or any of its attributes, then in XSLT 2.0+ you can achieve that using the `xsl:namespace` instruction. In 1.0 it's more convoluted.

You may find this post helpful: [How can I dynamically set the default namespace declaration of an XSLT transformation's output XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432818/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-default-namespace-declaration-of-an-xslt-transform)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So, I think my best option now is to use two transformers, as I can't use XSLT 2.0.